# Team Fortress Server Bots - Does nav_generate persist?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I run my own TF2 server for my friends and we occasionally balance the teams with bots. Unfortunately, the process of generating nav paths for the bots (`rcon nav_generate`) is a sad experience for any connected players.

I'm wondering: If I go through each map manually and run the `nav_generate` command, will the server remember the paths between reboots?

If not, are there any other ways to supply automatically generated nav paths to the game?

Comment: Can't you save NAV files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you run `nav_generate` for a map that is [not bot-supported](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Bots#Maps_with_official_bot_support%22not%20bot-supported%22), TF2 will save a `.nav` file in your `C:/Program Files(x86)/Steam/SteamApps/common/Team Fortress 2/tf/maps` folder, and any time you run the map with bots subsequently (as long as you still have the `.nav` file), you will not have to run the command again.

Also, it seems that only the computer running the server is required to have a `.nav` file for the map, since when I played on a unsupported map using bots, I did not find a new `.nav` file in the folder listed above. So, as long as you have the `.nav` file for the map, you should not have to regenerate each time you load an unsupported bot map.

Comment: This is an old answer, but you can also generate nav files on a TF2 client and upload them to a server.  Just bear in mind that you must set `sv_cheats 1` before you run `nav_generate`.